# skype4py P2P chat is not getting delivered

Tags: python, skype, skype4py

I'm using Python script & skype4py to send the chat message but its not getting delivered.

### Below is my script.

```
import Skype4Py
import sys

skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.Attach()
user = 'user1'
message = 'Build is successful.'
skype.SendMessage(user, message)
```

---

You can see the message is not getting delivered, its just showing circle.
[message loading image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNx9x.jpg)